# Expand, simplify, and get rid of Abs[] of a multi-variable polynomial

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

Given a polynomial that $poly = ((-1 + t_1^2) (-1 + t_2^2) (1 - t_2^2 + t_2^4))/(\sqrt{t_1^2} \cdot(t_2^2)^{3/2})$. I would like to expand and simplify this polynomial into the form $poly = \sum_{i\in I}c_i t_1^a \cdot t_2^b $, where $c_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, without any Abs[].

To expand and simplify it, I used

```
Expand[Simplify[poly, v > 0]]
```

where $v$ is the list of variables of this polynomial. The condition $v>0$ is to avoid terms like $\sqrt{t^2}$. However, this function gives the result:

```
1/(Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) - t1^2/(Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) - (2 t2^2)/(
 Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) + (2 t1^2 t2^2)/(Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) + (2 t2^4)/(
 Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) - (2 t1^2 t2^4)/(Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) - t2^6/(
 Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3) + (t1^2 t2^6)/(Abs[t1] Abs[t2]^3)
```

All the methods I found online to remove Abs[] introduced terms like $\sqrt{t^2}$, which are not desired.

I am new to Mathematica, so any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Could try `Simplify[poly, v ∈ PositiveReals]`

Comment: `Expand[Simplify[poly, Thread[v > 0]]]`